# can someone explain why im getting this error with Timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer

Why am i getting an error with the timer? below the code it states what the error is.  I cant figure out what im doing wrong.... can anyone help me

```
       import java.util.Timer;
       import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
       import javax.swing.JPanel;

       /**
        *
      * @author Rich
      */
     public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
         Dude p;
        Image img;
       Timer time;

        public Board() {
         p = new Dude();
        addKeyListener(new AL());
         setFocusable(true);
          ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("images.jpg");
          img = i.getImage();
          time = new Timer(5,this);
          time.start();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        p.move();
        repaint();
         }
```

Basically the error im getting is

```
no  suitable constructor found for Timer(int,OurGame.Board)
constructor java.util.Timer.Timer(java.lang.String,boolean) is not applicable
  (actual argument int cannot be converted to java.lang.String by method invocation conversion)
constructor java.util.Timer.Timer(java.lang.String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor java.util.Timer.Timer(boolean) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor java.util.Timer.Timer() is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: Exactly as the error states; there's no `Timer` ctor that takes a `Board` argument.

Comment: yeah I was using the wrong timer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should import `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `java.util.Timer`.

Answer (score 3):

You imported `java.util.Timer`. Use `javax.swing.Timer`.
Not your mistake, you see it a lot.

For the docs, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html.

Answer (score -2):

the 'this' variable in the following line:

```
time = new Timer(5,this);
```

refers to the current class, and the Timer Class doesn't know what to do with that ;)

Comment: Very wrong, his class implemented ActionListener, so it is a valid argument. Read the docs first, or try it yourself.